# How to install Ruby Gem without uing the command prompt in Windows 7

Tags: ruby, windows, installation, rubygems

I am at work and do not have access to the command prompt. I want to install a ruby gem or ten and the only way I know is the classic "gem install blah".

If I download the desired gems on a USB drive (not sure how to do this), is it even possible to then install the gems manually by placing the files in specific areas of the ruby program?

In case it is important, this is the message I get when trying to enter anything into the cmp promt, "Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601] Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved. The command prompt has been disabled by your administrator. Press any key to continue . . .".

Thanks in advance for your input!

Comment: Can you make a batch file with the commands in it and run that?

Comment: Please excuse my ignorance, I am not exactly sure what you mean. How do I make a batch file and what commands would I insert? Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download the .gem file directly from https://rubygems.org/, and extract its contents using Winrar or equivalent.

Then you'll have to figure it out the correct .rb file, and import it into your script.

Example:

1. download the example.gem file
2. extract it to the example folder
3. put the example folder within your script
4. in your script, load './example/example.rb'

But, is this really a requirement? Using ruby with Windows is kinda messy itself, and this hack is going to slow you down even more.

Regards

Comment: touché. Yeah, working with ruby in windows is a pain most of the time but I am forced to use the window OS at work. So what you are saying is 1) go to ruby gems 2) download gem and extract files 3) find out ruby file to use 4) reference said ruby file in my script 5) success ?

Comment: have you tried the terminal emulator http://cmder.net/ ?
if you have access to it, it will solve your problem and make easier to work with ruby in windows.

Comment: I didn't even know about that terminal emulator. I am downloading it now. I will report back with the details. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Sad times, the Cmder gives me a similar message and forces me to exit. I will need to try another way.